# NetBeans IDE Java 1.4 compatibility: compiler not warning on JDK 5+ classes/methods

Tags: netbeans, compiler-construction, java

When NetBeans 7 (or NetBeans 3.6) is compiling with `-source 1.4` enabled, why doesn't it warn when compiling with methods (or classes) introduced `@since 1.5` or `@since 1.6`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`javac` docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) imply that the `-source` option is about *language features*, not *library features*.

> **-source** *release*
>   Specifies the version of source code accepted. The following values for *release* are allowed:
>
> - **1.3** The compiler does not support assertions, generics, or other
>     language features introduced after JDK
>     1.3.
> - **1.4** The compiler accepts code containing assertions, which were
>     introduced in JDK 1.4.
> - **1.5** The compiler accepts code containing generics and other language
>     features introduced in JDK 5.
> - **5** Synonym for 1.5.
> - **1.6** This is the default value. No language changes were introduced in
>     Java SE 6. However, encoding errors in
>     source files are now reported as
>     errors, instead of warnings, as
>     previously.
> - **6** Synonym for 1.6.